# ColorSync found bad profile on Mac. What are the possible side effects?

Tags: color-management, color-spaces, macintosh, adobe, macbook

Today something led me to discover `ColorSync Utility` under `Applications > Utilities`. Upon `Verify` I discovered 9 bad profiles on my Mac.

```
Searching for profiles...
Checking 63 profiles...
/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/EW-GRAY18
   Tag ‘desc’: Tag size is not correct. 
   Tag ‘desc’: Description tag has a bad Macintosh string. 
/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/EW-GRAY22
   Tag ‘desc’: Tag size is not correct. 
   Tag ‘desc’: Description tag has a bad Macintosh string. 
/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/EW-sRGB
   Tag ‘desc’: Tag size is not correct. 
   Tag ‘desc’: Description tag has a bad Macintosh string. 
/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/EW-RGB18
   Tag ‘desc’: Tag size is not correct. 
   Tag ‘desc’: Description tag has a bad Macintosh string. 
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/VideoNTSC.icc
   Header message digest (MD5) is not correct. 
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/VideoHD.icc
   Header message digest (MD5) is not correct. 
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/VideoPAL.icc
   Header message digest (MD5) is not correct. 
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/Recommended/image-P3.icc
   Header message digest (MD5) is not correct. 
/Library/Application Support/Adobe/Color/Profiles/JapanColor2011Coated.icc
   Tag ‘desc’: Description tag has a bad Unicode string. 
Verify done. Found 9 bad profiles.
```

I recently started using Lightroom, Photoshop, Final Cut Pro, etc.  I'm wondering if having these bad profiles can impact my production work in a way that I am unaware of.

I have little idea if they are actively used. I manually don't fiddle with any profiles in my workflow. My DSLR images utilize ProPhoto profile, and on my Mac, I convert them to AdobeRGB or sRGB profiles before export.  Is there a way to find out if they are in active use?

What *(if any)* are the possible side effects of having these bad profiles on a MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the `desc` tags are not used for any functionality. They are mainly for having a human-readable description of what's in the profile. According to [Apple TechNote 1160](https://www.fenestrated.net/mac/mirrors/Apple%20Technotes%20(As%20of%202002)/tn/tn1160.html):

> The ICC Profile Format Specification (available at http://www.color.org) includes a Description tag ('desc'), designed to provide more information about a profile than can be contained in a file name. This is especially critical on file systems with 8.3 names. The tag data can consist of up to three separate pieces (strings) of information for a profile. These different strings are designed to allow for display in different languages or on different computer systems. Applications typically use one of the strings to show profiles in a list or a pop-up menu.

You are unlikely to want to use NTSC or PAL color profiles in photo editing. For Final Cut Pro work, it shouldn't be a problem as Final Cut Pro now works in the Rec-2020 color space. It will use profiles built into the app for converting between something like NTSC and Rec-2020 and wouldn't rely on a user or device-installed profile.